# How to return current value of loop

Tags: arrays, loops

I have a function that have some data (array), I want it to return always one value, it can be string or one element array. Dont know how to do that. Code example is below. Can you help me?

```js
function somefunction() {

var data = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
   arr = [];

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
 arr.push(value);
  console.log(value)
});

return arr;
}

somefunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think it should work, but it doesnt

```js
function somefunction() {

var data = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
   arr = [],
    i;

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
 arr.push(value);
  i++;
  console.log(value)
});

return arr[i];
}

somefunction()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you return whole array thats why it return all value

Comment: yeah, i tried to return current index in second snippet